# Re-open the Horse vs. Dovahkin "race" question

Tags: discussion, bounty, reopen

Some days ago, I posted this question:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49415/at-what-point-does-the-horse-provide-little-to-no-benefit-to-the-dovahkin

If I recall correctly, it was quickly closed as "Not a Real Question" or something similar.  Then, after some clarification as to its usefulness, it was re-opened.  After that, it was suggested that the question may be a duplicate.  But, for some reason, the close reason that won out the last time around was "Not Constructive".

Following the suggestion of those proposing the question was a duplicate, I posted a rather substantial bounty on the proposed-duplicate question, here:

[Is a horse actually faster than running?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36304/6274)

Now, that bounty is about to expire in a few days and the question has not seen any activity since I posted the bounty.  Unless someone gives an appropriate answer before the bounty expires, could my original question please be re-opened?

EDIT:  I've updated my question to hopefully clarify its intent further, though I'm not sure at this point what added value that has to anyone who's already judged it.

Comment: I don't quite understand how those two things are related

Comment: @JuanManuel Essentially, I suppose one (the older) question asks "Is a horse actually faster than running?" and the other says "Is it possible for a trained Dovahkiin to overcome the horse's normal advantage?".  The latter is considered by some to be territory that could (should?) have been covered in answers to the former, but wasn't.

Comment: To prevent it being considered a duplicate, you might want to make the title more explicit.  "Can I outrun a horse using Whirlwind Sprint?"  It will come down to how much extra distance the shout gives you, and how often you can use it.  With all the correct perks, I would guess the answer is yes.

Comment: @JuanManuel My argument was that any practical problem posed in the question about dovahkiin being theoretically faster would have already been covered by the first question.  There's no practical benefit to being faster under very certain circumstances, so I felt the second question was a duplicate as far as practicality is concerned

Comment: There's no real harm in having both open, though.  Dupes don't have to be made 100% of the time, especially when they're not perfect dupes.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, this is a bad question, and I think it overlaps in some ways on several different types of "bad questions."

The FAQ reads:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

This is a very open ended question, because there are tons of factors involved in the test of who is faster.  With all the restrictions and permutations, it might cause debate about what is "fair" or if a particular testing methodology was complete, so I'd be tempted to vote to close it "not constructive."

It's also not based on a situation that people playing this game actually face.  Fast travel, spells, werewolf form, stamina potions, etc, are all things that actual gamers could (and would!) use to cover a long distance without a horse.  By placing a bunch of qualifications on the question, you're limiting its scope, and decreasing its usefulness to other readers of the question and its answers.  Therefore, this might fall under "too localized."

If you remove all the restrictions, and distill it down, you're essentially asking "Can I get to my destination faster on a horse, or is there no benefit to doing so?" which is a duplicate of the question "Is a horse actually faster than running?" - so I'd be tempted to vote to close as a duplicate.

Therefore, I think even if you're sure it's not a duplicate, the question could be closed on at least two other grounds (and these are just the ones I, as someone who has never played Skyrim, can think of), so I don't think reopening it is the right answer.

Comment: Some of this I've mentioned before:  Fast-travel doesn't always get you all the way there.  I'm not aware of any spells that re-generate stamina, but please point me to them if there are some.  Werewolf form brings along too many limitations (gotta stay away from towns the whole trip, and hope you're not nearby anyone when you transform) to be preferable for me.  And potions have weight, so I try to minimize the amount that I carry at any given time.

Comment: @Iszi, while I'm sure that you have reasons for imposing the restrictions you've imposed, it still contributes to it being too localized.  If you think the experiment has merit to answering the question of whether a horse contributes to your speed under certain conditions, why not perform the experiment yourself? Then contribute it (along with your methodology) as an answer to the "Is a horse actually faster than running?" question.  It's a popular question, and the application of SCIENCE! is always grounds for increased attention.

Comment: I don't currently have a saved game that's in a good position to properly perform the experiment, and am not immediately inclined to spend the 8-ish hours I know it will take to get a game there.  I was sort-of hoping someone else with such a save point might go ahead and do it, if I didn't get around to it myself first.  And I do know we've got one or two people around here who have some interest in play-testing.

Comment: @Iszi There's a talent, Respite, pretty low in the Restoration tree, that makes all your healing spells restore stamina as well as health.

Comment: @Sterno Thanks.  I'll keep that in mind.